# Using the db2cli on OSX

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I want to check a DB2 configuration to see if SSL is enabled.
I am using OSX and I don't have any DB2 or cli installed locally.  The db2 database is on a server which I can access with the username and pw.

I was looking at [this article](http://fm4dd.com/database/howto-encrypt-IBMdb2-jdbc.htm), which lists this command to get the SSL information:

```
db2 get database manager configuration |grep SSL
```

How is this being run?  I tried downloading the `db2cli` but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Can anyone provide easy to follow instructions to do this?

Comment: Since it turns out you're connecting to IBM i, your best bet to figure out SSL configuration is to speak with the server administrator. The usual way to connect to IBM i is to use [i Access Client](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1026805) but you need to know the SSL configuration in order to set it up, so there's catch 22 here. In other words, your question presents an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you _don't_ need and cannot use db2cli for what you ultimately want -- finding out SSL configuration on the server.

Comment: db2cli cannot be used to access DB2 for i on IBM i unless you have DB2 Connect. this is a VERY expensive program. Your best bet is to ask the system administrator.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll close this as i'M way off here

Answer (score 0):

You can see the database manager configuration via SQL is you query the view `sysibmadm.dbmcfg`

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022029.html

---

You can get database configuration via SQL is you query the view `sysibmadm.dbcfg`

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022028.html

---

You can get database registy variables via SQL is you query the table function `ENV_GET_REG_VARIABLES`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ENV_GET_REG_VARIABLES(-2, 0))
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0058678.html

Comment: tried this and got an error: [42704][-204] [SQL0204] DBMCFG in SYSIBMADM type *FILE not found.

Comment: Your error shows you are connecting to DB2 for i (aka AS/400). My reply assumed you were connecting to DB2 for LUW

Comment: The link in your question is also for DB2 for LUW. You need to look at the IBM i manual, e.g. maybe here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/ddp/rbal1sslddm.htm

Comment: well I have managed to get the db2cli installed but it looks like this is different to the db command.  I'm a bit lost at this point.

Comment: db2cli and db2 Command Line Processor (CLP) are just diffetent utilities. `db2cli` is essentially for testing CLI/ODBC data sources. It's part of  the `Data Server Driver package`, doesn't require db2 instace creation, can't run db2 commands (sql statements only). `Db2 CLP` is not a CLI/ODBC application, not included into the `Data Server Driver package`, requires db2 instance creation, can run both sql statements and db2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any machine with SSL at hand to test this, but with `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.1:port` you can see if there's an actual handshake being processed. I don't know which port db2cli utilizes, though.